# I think Flask wants me to instantiate the app in my tests.py file but i dont know how to

Tags: python, unit-testing, flask, tdd

I think Flask wants me to instantiate the app but i dont know how to, am getting the error `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'app'`

*Traceback*:

```
C:\Users\Mlamba\Envs\vir\Scripts\python.exe D:/code/web-projects/Bucketlist-Python-Flask-project/tests.py
E
======================================================================
ERROR: test_index_view (__main__.ViewTests)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/code/web-projects/Bucketlist-Python-Flask-project/tests.py", line 11, in test_index_view
    response = make_response(render_template("index.html"))
  File "C:\Users\Mlamba\Envs\vir\lib\site-packages\flask\templating.py", line 132, in render_template
    ctx.app.update_template_context(context)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'app'

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.001s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

*Run.py* file:

```
from app import app

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

**init**.py file:

```
from flask import Flask

# Load the views
from app import views

# Initialize the app
app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=True)

# Load the config file
app.config.from_object('config')
```

*Test file*:

```
import unittest

from flask import render_template, make_response


class ViewTests(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_index_view(self):
        """
        Test that index page is accessible without login
        """
        response = make_response(render_template("index.html"))
        self.assertEquals(response.status_code, 200)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

*Directory structure:*

```
|-- README.md
|-- __pycache__
|   `-- config.cpython-36.pyc
|-- app
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- __pycache__
|   |   |-- __init__.cpython-36.pyc
|   |   `-- views.cpython-36.pyc
|   |-- models.py
|   |-- static
|   |-- templates
|   |   |-- index.html
|   |   `-- layout.html
|   `-- views.py
|-- config.py
|-- requirements.txt
|-- run.py
`-- tests.py
```

Comment: Your test doesn't do anything at all related to what the docstring says, ie checking that the index page is accessible without login.

Comment: However, for your actual problem, please show the full traceback.

Comment: Added Traceback to the question

Comment: @A.Mlamba I have edited my answer so you have an example. hope this helped :)
p.s. I see that you are new so I will tell you this: If some answer helped you `upvote  it` and the best answer `accept it` by clicking the ✓ next to the answer

Answer (score 4):

You have never imported your `app` so you cant test it.
Look at the [documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/testing/) on how to import the app and how to test it.

Here is an example of a basic `flask` test:

**main.py:**

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return "Hello world!" 

if __name__ = '__main__':
    app.run()
```

**test_app.py:**

```
import unittest
from main import app

class FlaskTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.app = app.test_client()
        self.app.testing = True
        pass

    def test_num1(self):
        rv = self.app.get('/')
        assert b'Hello world' in rv.data


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

You run the tests with: `python test_app.py`

Comment: I have the same issues as OP but in my main I have the function `def create_app` that returns the flask object, so in this case how does one import app into the test file?

Answer (score 0):

While I don't know for sure. I am guessing you forgot to import your app module into run.py. Please also post the contents of your run.py and **init**.py just to be more sure.

In your run.py you have to `import app` and also run the function `app.run()` both are necessary and should be the first steps to do in your app after that just do a `python run.py` and a server will start at port-number 5000 I believe.

EDIT:
If you see your init.py you have imported `from app import views` this is wrong because from the context of init.py you're already in app and no need to type from app again because the import will try to find a folder or a package named app within the current hierarchy.
change that to just `import views` and you should be on your way. Also as Kemis pointed out, import your app in your unittest files.

Comment: added them to the question